# Copy Excel range and paste to word from VB.Net app causes a 0x800A03EC error when used more than one

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-word

In my code, Copy Excel range and paste to word from is done correctly, but when I repeat this code for a new range app it causes a 0x800A03EC error when used more than once.

[image]

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(TempWord & "word", My.Resources._1, True)
            Dim sWORDFileName = TempWord & "word"
            Form1.oExcel.Range("B1:AM46").Copy()
            OWORD.DisplayAlerts = False
            OWORD.Documents.Open(sWORDFileName)
            OWORD.Selection.PasteSpecial(Link:=False, DataType:=9, Placement:=0, DisplayAsIcon:=False) 'Asked question to get this 
            OWORD.Selection.TypeParagraph()
            OWORD.Visible = True
            Form1.oExcel.Range("B49:AM93").Copy()
            OWORD.DisplayAlerts = False
            OWORD.Documents.Open(sWORDFileName)
            OWORD.Selection.PasteSpecial(Link:=False, DataType:=9, Placement:=0, DisplayAsIcon:=False) 'Asked question to get this 
            OWORD.Selection.TypeParagraph()
            OWORD.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error number Office applications are automated on the server-side, here is what MS states for that:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. Also you may find third-party components designed for the server-side execution helpful.